# Read picture as BGR mode instead of RGB

Tags: 16.04, colors

I've got some picture in BGR mode, but I don't find a way to display them in BGR; all application read them with RGB, so it's not really good to see as you can see below :

[image]

The main color of the front car is a "black green", but we don't see at all the red color in the car headlight. I try to use `gimp` or `kolourpaint4` to change the color mode, but I didn't find how to do that.

Comment: I think you can try adopting [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/982642/swap-rgba-channels-around-in-gimp).

Comment: you might want to answer your question, so that other peoples with the same need would figure it more quickly.

Comment: I let you do it, it's fairer (you re the one which gives the link)

Comment: You already know how to do it, whilst I don't *(because the linked answer needs to be adopted anyway)*, neither I have incentive in figuring that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Hi-Angel for the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/982642/swap-rgba-channels-around-in-gimp) in the comment

Using Gimp, open the picture; in the menu, go to *Color* -> *Composants* -> *Decompose* and decompose with RGB mode (don't forget to check the option *Decompose in trace*).

You will get 3 composants, 1 of each color (red, blue and green), but red and blue are still inversed. To remedy that (with a single composant window), do the same thing but select *Compose*.

[image]

Let the color model to **RGB**, but inverse **Red** and **Blue**, and validate; let see the result below

[image]

As you can see, the picture is not read in BGR mode, but red and blue composant had been inversed so the picture had been transformed from BGR to RGB (the car is well colored now)

PS: don't bother me about luminosity level, I was testing it ;)